# Include Files using Wildcard into a folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\resources\hbm\*.hbm.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to include a bunch of xml files into my C# project.  Works fine.

But, I don't want them in the "root level" of my project, I would rather see them in a subfolder in my project.

For example, this file is included into a `Mapping` folder in Visual Studio:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Mapping\User.hbm.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That's what I want for my `*.hbm.xml` files.

I can't figure out how to do it and still keep my wildcard `*.hbm.xml` part and also keep the actual files in a different directory.

I've looked at MSDN's doc on MSBUILD and items, but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think **you can't** use links and wildcard at the same time.

You could use this notation to link to include User.hbm.xml file in Mapping folder in Visual Studio :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\resources\hbm\User.hbm.xml">
    <Link>Mapping\User.hbm.xml</Link>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

But you can't do that

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\resources\hbm\**\*.hbm.xml">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I decided to just write a script that updates my CSPROJ file.  I added it as an Exec task in my msbuild script.  Works fine, but is a bit icky.

Comment: Care to share the script? :-)

Answer (score 46):

Perhaps this has changed in MSBuild since the original answer was posted, but it is possible to use both wildcards and links at the same time. For example, I use the following block in a C# project to import data files into a test library.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\SOMENAME.Tests\data\**\*.*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <Link>data\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

The only disadvantage I've seen so far is that MSBuild recreates the folder names on the file system (ie `$(ProjectPath)\data\somesubfolder`) which is a little annoying but not a huge issue.

As a test, I also tried the OP's request of embedding resources, using the following snippet, and again this seemed to work fine - dotPeek showed the resources were present in the compiled assembly in addition to being present in the Solution Explorer.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource  Include="..\SOMENAME.Tests\data\**\*.*">
      <Link>resources\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

(This was using Visual Studio 2013 and still works as of VS2019)

Update 08Jun2021: The above syntax works is fine for old style csproj files, but if you are using the new SDK format, the syntax is a little different, albeit simpler.

The OP's original question of wildcard embedding can be accomplished with the following

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="data\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And to have wildcard file copies for changed or missing files.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="data\**\*.*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I can confirm, that this works with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Still works for .Net 5 projects in Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create the logical name based on some regex (for only one folder depth). The root namespace I want is `Agility.BmsData.Create` and and example of the final name of the resource could be `Agility.BmsData.Create.tables.mytable.sql` where the file is in a folder `tables\mytable.sql`

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\AgilityDatabase\Create\**\*.sql" >
            <!-- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022 -->
            <!--     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022 -->
            <LogicalName>
                Agility.BmsData.Create.$(
                    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("%(Directory)", "(?&lt;=\\)[^\\]+(?=[\\]*$)")
                ).%(Filename)%(Extension)
            </LogicalName>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
```

It is also possible to customise the `Link` attribute of the `EmbeddedResource` element but the value needs to be suitably encoded for embedding in an xml attribute.
Following on from the above example, I have sql files located in the database project on a relative path to the current project of `..\..\AgilityDatabase\Create\` and I want to mimic the file structure (and resource names) in my other project. I can use the following MsBuild command `$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("%(Directory)", "(?<=\\AgilityDatabase\\Create\\).+$"))\%(Filename)%(Extension)`

So my Item group becomes:

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\AgilityDatabase\Create\**\*.sql"
                  Link="Create\$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(&quot;%(Directory)&quot;, &quot;(?&lt;=\\AgilityDatabase\\Create\\).+$&quot;))\%(Filename)%(Extension)">
</EmbeddedResource>
```